# Exception in car: () is not a pair

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp

I have this program I have to make:

[image]

I've been able to make a program that correctly figures out if something exists in the tree, but it breaks if something ISN'T in the tree.
[image]

[image]
 The debug message isn't helpful at all. The only place I ever use `car` is in the 3 auxiliary functions. Can someone explain what this means/what I should do? I've been tinkering around and can't find a fix.

The following is what I have so far:

```
(define (val T)
    (car T)
)

(define (left T)
    (car (cdr T))
)

(define (right T)
    (car (cdr (cdr T)))
)

(define (tree-member-helper? V T)
    (if (not (null? (val T)))

        (if (< V (val T))
            (tree-member-helper? V (left T))
            (if (> V (val T))
                (tree-member-helper? V (right T))
                 #t
            )
        )
        '()
    )
)
```

Comment: It may be helpful to include your definitions of the auxiliary functions where you use car.

Comment: lol @AzureHeights how silly. Thought I did, guess not. They're there now :)

Comment: You should terminate the recursion when the tree is empty. Think about what `(val T)` is for a few minutes.

Comment: T should never be null, I check it .... Oh... `(if (not (null? (val T)))` I think that's it...

Comment: On another note, the only "false-y" value in Scheme is `#f`. (`'()` is false-y in Lisp, but not in Scheme.)

Comment: Mandatory reading: http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~wiseman/humor/large-programs.html

Comment: `(car (cdr (cdr x)))` -> `(caddr x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part:

```
(not (null? (val T)))
```

You are checking if the **value** is not null. A typical iteration of a tree one checks if the value is the empty tree or not. In your case `()` since the node `(1 () ())` is a node with value 1 and no empty trees as children.

First when you have established that the node is not empty you can do `car` and `cdr` on them (or call functions that do that).

Now why do we expect `caddr` to work without checking you might ask. Well if you send a invalid tree like `'(1 (2) (3))` it doesn't and you get a similar error. You could fix this by making a function that checks that the node is indeed valid:

```
(define (valid-node? node)
  (and (list? node)
       (= (length node) 3)
       (number? (car node))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't break because the value isn't in the tree, it breaks because `car` won't operate on an empty list (it requires a pair). The first example succeeds because it finds the 1 before having to use `car` on an empty list.

In order to get around this, I would check to make sure that each call to `right` or `left` is actually operating on a pair before calling them.
Unfortunately I don't know Scheme, or really Lisp in general, well enough to provide an example, but hopefully that gets you started in the right direction.